# Filtering the occurrence of an IP/port number by date/time in firewall log with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple, large, csv files of firewall logs that consist of columns:

```
['Date/time',
 'Syslog priority',
 'Operation',
 'Message code',
 'Protocol',
 'Source IP',
 'Destination IP',
 'Source hostname',
 'Destination hostname',
 'Source port',
 'Destination port',
 'Destination service',
 'Direction',
 'Connections built',
 'Connections torn down']
```

Here is an MCVE for the data

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

csvdata = StringIO("""
'Date/time', 'Syslog priority', 'Operation', 'Message code', 'Protocol', 'Source IP', 'Destination IP', 'Source hostname', 'Destination hostname', 'Source port', 'Destination port', 'Destination service', 'Direction', 'Connections built', 'Connections torn down'
[SAMPLE ROW DATA HERE]
""")
```

I want to filter out specific columns by Source IP and Destination port, and display how many times they occur per hour.

I am using pandas, and combined the multiple csv files together into one (over 10 million lines):

```
concat = pd.concat([fLog,fLog1,fLog2,fLog3,fLog4])
```

I tried to sort by Source IP in accordance to Date/time:

```
concat[['Date/time','Source IP']][concat['Source IP'] == '172.20.1.5']
```

and received along the lines of:

```
    Date/time   Source IP
443 13/Apr/2011 08:53:32    172.20.1.5
444 13/Apr/2011 08:53:32    172.20.1.5
576 13/Apr/2011 08:53:43    172.20.1.5
2747    13/Apr/2011 08:55:33    172.20.1.5
...
```

I want it to print by hour, so I tried:

```
concat['Date/time']=pd.to_datetime(concat['Date/time'])

concat.pivot_table(index=pd.Grouper(freq='H', key='Date/time'),columns='Source IP')


Connections built   ... Connections torn down
Source IP   (empty) 10.200.150.2    10.200.150.201  10.200.150.206  10.200.150.207  10.200.150.208  10.200.150.209  172.20.1.5  192.168.1.1 192.168.1.14    ... 192.168.2.91    192.168.2.92    192.168.2.93    192.168.2.94    192.168.2.95    192.168.2.96    192.168.2.97    192.168.2.98    192.168.2.99    192.168.7.151
Date/time                                                                                   
2011-04-13 08:00:00 0.478814    0.333333    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.500000    1.0 0.0 ... NaN 0.692308    0.500000    0.500000    0.503401    0.500000    0.508621    0.500000    0.520000    NaN
2011-04-13 09:00:00 0.469044    0.363636    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.500000    1.0 0.0 ... 0.513889    0.506410    0.520833    0.477778    0.496781    0.504132    0.501340    0.502326    0.453271    NaN
2011-04-13 10:00:00 0.486111    0.323077    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.500000    1.0 0.0 ... 0.363636    0.425000    0.383333    0.533333    0.522388    0.428571    0.421053    0.434783    0.512821    NaN
```

I want an output that shows the amount of times(sum) a given Source IP, and Destination port occur per hour:

Expected result would be:

```
Date/time           Source IP  Destination port Occurrence
2011-04-13 08:00:00 172.20.1.5       80             23
```

Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Grouping by the hour component of the datetime index and reporting the unique Source IP and frequency for that hour.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

csvdata = StringIO("""
Date/time,Syslogpriority,Operation,Messagecode,Protocol,SourceIP,DestinationIP,Sourcehostname,Destinationhostname,Sourceport,Destinationport,Destinationservice,Direction,Connectionsbuilt,Connectionstorndown
2019-08-01 01:00:00,a,b,c,d,e1,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n
2019-08-01 02:00:00,a,b,c,d,e1,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n
2019-08-01 02:30:00,a,b,c,d,e1,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n
2019-08-01 02:40:00,a,b,c,d,e1,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n
2019-08-01 02:00:00,a,b,c,d,e1,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n
2019-08-01 01:00:00,a,b,c,d,e2,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n
2019-08-01 02:00:00,a,b,c,d,e2,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n
2019-08-01 03:00:00,a,b,c,d,e3,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n """)

concat_df = pd.read_csv(csvdata, sep=",", index_col="Date/time", parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True)
concat_df['hour'] = concat_df.index.hour

grouped_df = concat_df.groupby([concat_df['hour'], concat_df['SourceIP']])['SourceIP'].count()

# join back to source data
result_df = concat_df.join(grouped_df, on=['hour', 'SourceIP'], rsuffix='_Occurrence')
print(result_df[['hour', 'SourceIP', 'SourceIP_Occurrence']])
```

```
                     hour SourceIP  SourceIP_Occurrence
Date/time                                              
2019-08-01 01:00:00     1       e1                    1
2019-08-01 02:00:00     2       e1                    4
2019-08-01 02:30:00     2       e1                    4
2019-08-01 02:40:00     2       e1                    4
2019-08-01 02:00:00     2       e1                    4
2019-08-01 01:00:00     1       e2                    1
2019-08-01 02:00:00     2       e2                    1
2019-08-01 03:00:00     3       e3                    1
```

Comment: Ah! Beautiful! Thank you so much! And if I wanted to sort by a certain IP could I just edit it like so?: ```grouped_df = concat_df.groupby([concat_df['hour'], concat_df['SourceIP']=='172.20.1.5'])['SourceIP'].count()```

Comment: That runs on my side and returns if the IP address is present in that hour.  But it is filtering for the IP address, not sorting.  Note: The answer works for hours of the day for all days in the input data.